# Fetch and echo submitted text to individual li/div?

Tags: php, html-lists

This is my first post here...

I have a question regaring a news feed related function in html/php that I'm writing. You could say it's similar to "the Wall" which Facebook are using.

So I have a input field on the top of the page, which posts the text the user has written and inserts to my database.

The text later gets printed out on the page using echo.

So far so good. I'm fetching things from the database, such as message, author, time etc. I've been able to show one message, with all the information shown in their right positions.
The thing is; I want each submitted message to be echo'ed out in individual divs. I'm using an unordered list to create these individual containers in which each message will be shown.

Now I'd like some assistance on the logic part. How should I do this?

What I've been thinking about so far is posting a hidden ID with an increment on each submitted message. Then the website will check if there exist a message with an ID higher than the latest message shown on the website. If there is a message with a higher ID, then this particular message will be echoed out in another li. I'm not sure how these new li's will be created automatically though. Maybe I could echo the li out too, if there exist a value of ID higher than the latest displayed.

Also I'm wonder about the fetch function. How can I specify what I want to fetch from a table and later echo this fetched data into a specified div?

TLDR?
What I'd like to happen.

1. The user writes some text and submits.
2. The text gets inserted to database.
3. Fetch latest inserted text.
4. Echo the fetched text into a new li.

If there's anything I should clearify, please let me know.
Thanks on advance.

Edit;
Let's say I have this big feed with a lot of posts, but I only want to show some of them. Let's say I have four users, two of them have the viewID 0 and the other two have the viewID 1. When a user with the ID 0 submits somthing, only the users with the ID 0 will see this message. How will this be achieved? I'm thinking that when the user posts a message a hidden viewID is posted too. After that SELECT from database where viewID = 0 etc. Maybe this could be done using cookies/session?
I don't know if this is a huge step from what is written above?

However. I kind of forgot that you can echo html, so my individual li/div's with the fetched texts could be done this way, fetching and echo:ing instantly on submit.

Comment: Do you want to auto-refresh all messages on your feed? that what you are refering to when you say `create automatically` or you want to insert in real time without re-loading the page?

Comment: No, not really. In my post I forgot that I can echo html. So the li's can be echo'ed instantly/automatically on submit. But yes, that's something I'll look up later too, with the wall refreshing on submitting. I'd be thankful if you give me a piece of advice on that  :)

Comment: to not extend this i would tell you for real time feed you need javascript, ajax, and a method to check everytime the server, could be polling or a timeout or something else, but if you have some question let me know.

Comment: Thank you Welling. I will look further into this later on. By the way, are you being able to refresh all people viewing the page when something is submitted, or can this only be achieved on the person who submitted's computer? (Just like a chat)?

Comment: This should work like a "chat", just like facebook, you can archive and everyone connect it to your server will view thoses changes as well, this is up to you.

Comment: Interesting. Where should I start/what should I learn? Give me some Google directioning;)

Answer (score 0):

You can echo out `html` with `php`. As for fetching, I recommend the object-oriented way

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name" // note this could be of many forms depending on your needs.

$result = $sql->query();

while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
  echo '<li><div>' . $row->comment . '</div></li>';
}
```

So you create a new div inside a li for every query in the database, aka for every post.

All this code goes into a single `ul` element, wrapped in the php starting tags.

Comment: I'll try it out. But this should work, yes. I kind of forgot that you can echo html out. Or well, I mentioned it in my post "Maybe I could echo the li out too".

Comment: "Maybe I could echo the li out too" TLDR, well half of it. :P

Comment: I'm kind of new here on stackoverflow, so I don't know if you got a notice saying I edited my post. If you did not, then I just wanted you to know that I did. I added something, which I think might be adding some trouble using this method. Check it out if you want. You've been helpful either way, hehe. Thank you!